# Получить единственный уникальный элемент последовательности, в которой остальные элементы имеют всего один дубликат

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется класс, который хранит нечетное количество элементов таким образом, что все элементы имеют только один дубликат, и только один элемент уникальный. Вот первоначальный вид класса:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <numeric>

#define RANGE(x) std::begin(x), std::end(x) 
template<size_t mid, int max = 1000>
class Backup {
    enum { N = 2 * mid + 1 };
    int arr[N]; //
public:
    //каким то образом инициализируем массив нужным нам способом
    Backup() 
    {
        std::set<int> s;
        while (s.size() != mid)
            s.insert(rand() % max;
        //две половинки одних и тех же уникальных элементов
        std::copy(RANGE(s), arr);
        std::copy(RANGE(s), arr + mid);
        //единственный уникальный элемент 
        arr[N - 1] = max + rand() % max;
        //перемешаем
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 g(rd());
        std::shuffle(arr, arr + N, g);
    }    
    void print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        std::copy(arr, arr + N, std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
        os << std::endl;
    }
    //получить единственный уникальный элемент
    int get_unique_item() const
    {
        //слышком усложненная реализация
        std::map<int, int> m;
        for (const int i : arr)
            ++m[i];
        for (const auto p : m)
            if (p.second == 1)
                return p.first;
    }

};
int main() {      
    Backup<100> v;
    v.print(std::cout);
    std::cout << v.get_unique_item();
    return 0;
}
```

Но тут для получения уникального элемента (реализация `get_unique_item`) использован std::map и выполняется два прохода по коллекциям, поиск в таблице... 
**Как может выглядеть наиболее упрощенный вариант реализации этой функции?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выполнить исключающее или для всех элементов.

Дубликаты (из условия - у каждого, если есть, то только один дубль) - обнулятся.

Реализация... Ну, примерно

```
int x = 0;
for (const int i : arr) x^=i;
return x;
```

Вот ваш [код](https://ideone.com/PiYdLN) для убедиться :).

Comment: arr[0] ^= arr[i] ? так?

Comment: Ну, тогда вы будете менять `arr[0]`, я не знаю, разрешено ли у вас это...

Comment: ну если индекс начинается с 1. Вообшем понятно. Я в школе решал такую задачу, а сейчас не мог. Конечно так, спасибо